Indonesian visa: "Error Facematching" & extension of the 30-day-visa
I'm a German trying to get a 60d tourist visa for Indonesia but the website is beyond bad: I uploaded my passport and a picture to https://evisa.imigrasi.go.id/front/register/wna, entered all the info and clicked the submit button. The only reaction that I get it "Error Facematching". Since I do not plan to have facial surgery, I don't know what I can do. Also, I have written an email to them and haven't received an answer for a week.
So I'm thinking about getting an e-VOA for 30d and then somehow hope that I can extend it online. I'm not sure about the translation, but on this site (https://www.imigrasi.go.id/berita/2023/01/30/anti-ribet-begini-alur-perpanjangan-electronic-visa-on-arrival-indonesia) it states (auto-translated):

Foreign Nationals (WNA) who enter Indonesia using Electronic Visa on Arrival (e-VOA) now do not need to take care of an extension to the immigration office. To be able to stay in Indonesia for the next 30 days, they simply apply for an e-VOA extension through the website molina.immigration.go.id, there is no need to scan for proof of entry (cap) from the Immigration Checkpoint

So I'm assuming I can just extend a 30d visa online after 15 days of being in Indonesia. And that is also assuming the website linked, which doesnt even work, is supposed to be https://imigrasi.go.id. But then the next thing is that they want my return flight. I booked one for after 58 days, but presenting this would only make sense for the extension, right? I mean, I don't know whether they usually give you problems when trying to extend, but I don't even know whether I should present my after-58d-return-flight or not.
Can anyone help with this? Thanks!
tl;dr

Is it hassle-free to get a 30d e-VOA and then extend it ONLINE while in the country?
How to fix the "Facematching error"? EDIT: Just tried another picture from the passport, now it worked
Which return flight to present when applying for the first e-VOA when my already purchased return flight is after 58 days? Can I present that one assuming an extension will go through?
Should I not even get the e-VOA but rather do it at the airport? Can that VOA also be extended online?


Have you tried providing a different picture? With as neutral as possible an expression, facing the camera, correctly sized and cantered (like for a passport picture, really). No glasses if you wear any. Ditto for the copy of your passport, make sure the photo is clear and especially devoid of glare.

I tried the same passport picture but 2 sliiightly different photos of me. As for their photo requirements, I'm not really sure, because they mention something with 50-60% height etc. And their preview picture is so small you can't read a thing.

Oh and it gets even better! Now that the facematching wasn't a problem anymore, I confirmed my mail address via the mail they sent me and guess what... when trying to log in or reset the password, it tells me "Email is not found in our system, please input the correct email."
Sorry, this is absolutely ridiculous, especially for a government website. I have never seen anything like this.

Update: after more than 7 attempts of writing to different mail addresses, I'm giving up on the eVisa and will get the visa on arrival, hoping that it will also be extended
